# how to add save option and few other things to this game ?

Tags: java, android

I already asked this question but because it was not clear I guess people were avoiding it.
 I dont want all of these things done together I just want one of them specially the savegame one. I need to know how the coding is so I could work on it and learn from it .

I wanted to edit this game to get some experience in programming. 
I want to add saving the game, total wins and losses and also use default option to the game as well as changing the velocity of the ball and time allowed.

Please show me how you would do it so  I can have a reference when Im doing it to make sure I did it right.

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.deitel.cannongame" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
  <activity android:name=".CannonGame" 
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
</manifest>
```

Cannongame java

```
// CannonGame.java
// Main Activity for the Cannon Game app.
package com.deitel.cannongame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class CannonGame extends Activity
{
 private GestureDetector gestureDetector; // listens for double taps
 private CannonView cannonView; // custom view to display the game

 // called when the app first launches
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call super's onCreate method
  setContentView(R.layout.main); // inflate the layout

  // get the CannonView
  cannonView = (CannonView) findViewById(R.id.cannonView);

  // initialize the GestureDetector
  gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, gestureListener);

  // allow volume keys to set game volume
  setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 } // end method onCreate

 // when the app is pushed to the background, pause it
 @Override
 public void onPause()
 {
  super.onPause(); // call the super method
  cannonView.stopGame(); // terminates the game
 } // end method onPause

 // release resources
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();
  cannonView.releaseResources();
} // end method onDestroy

// called when the user touches the screen in this Activity
 @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
  {
  // get int representing the type of action which caused this event
  int action = event.getAction();

  // the user user touched the screen or dragged along the screen
  if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
     action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
  {
     cannonView.alignCannon(event); // align the cannon
  } // end if

  // call the GestureDetector's onTouchEvent method
  return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
 } // end method onTouchEvent

 // listens for touch events sent to the GestureDetector
 SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener()
 {
  // called when the user double taps the screen
  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
  {
     cannonView.fireCannonball(e); // fire the cannonball
     return true; // the event was handled
   } // end method onDoubleTap
}; // end gestureListener
} // end class CannonGame
```

CannonView java

```
    // CannonView.java
    // Displays the Cannon Game
    package com.deitel.cannongame;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.SoundPool;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;

    public class CannonView extends SurfaceView 
       implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
       private CannonThread cannonThread; // controls the game loop
       private Activity activity; // to display Game Over dialog in GUI thread
       private boolean dialogIsDisplayed = false;   

       // constants for game play
       public static final int TARGET_PIECES = 7; // sections in the target
       public static final int MISS_PENALTY = 2; // seconds deducted on a miss
       public static final int HIT_REWARD = 3; // seconds added on a hit

       // variables for the game loop and tracking statistics
       private boolean gameOver; // is the game over?
       private double timeLeft; // the amount of time left in seconds
       private int shotsFired; // the number of shots the user has fired
       private double totalElapsedTime; // the number of seconds elapsed

       // variables for the blocker and target
       private Line blocker; // start and end points of the blocker
       private int blockerDistance; // blocker distance from left
       private int blockerBeginning; // blocker distance from top
       private int blockerEnd; // blocker bottom edge distance from top
       private int initialBlockerVelocity; // initial blocker speed multiplier
       private float blockerVelocity; // blocker speed multiplier during game

       private Line target; // start and end points of the target
       private int targetDistance; // target distance from left
       private int targetBeginning; // target distance from top
       private double pieceLength; // length of a target piece
       private int targetEnd; // target bottom's distance from top
       private int initialTargetVelocity; // initial target speed multiplier
       private float targetVelocity; // target speed multiplier during game

       private int lineWidth; // width of the target and blocker
       private boolean[] hitStates; // is each target piece hit?
       private int targetPiecesHit; // number of target pieces hit (out of 7)

       // variables for the cannon and cannonball
       private Point cannonball; // cannonball image's upper-left corner
       private int cannonballVelocityX; // cannonball's x velocity
       private int cannonballVelocityY; // cannonball's y velocity
       private boolean cannonballOnScreen; // is the cannonball on the screen
       private int cannonballSpeed; // cannonball speed
       private int cannonBaseRadius; // cannon base radius
       private int cannonLength; // cannon barrel length
       private Point barrelEnd; // the endpoint of the cannon's barrel
       private int cannonballRadius; // cannonball radius
    private int screenWidth; // width of the screen
       private int screenHeight; // height of the screen

       // constants and variables for managing sounds
       private static final int TARGET_SOUND_ID = 0;
       private static final int CANNON_SOUND_ID = 1;
       private static final int BLOCKER_SOUND_ID = 2;
       private SoundPool soundPool; // plays sound effects
       private Map<Integer, Integer> soundMap; // maps IDs to SoundPool

       // Paint variables used when drawing each item on the screen
       private Paint textPaint; // Paint used to draw text
       private Paint cannonballPaint; // Paint used to draw the cannonball
       private Paint cannonPaint; // Paint used to draw the cannon
       private Paint blockerPaint; // Paint used to draw the blocker
       private Paint targetPaint; // Paint used to draw the target
       private Paint backgroundPaint; // Paint used to clear the drawing area

       // public constructor
       public CannonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
       {
          super(context, attrs); // call super's constructor
          activity = (Activity) context; 

          // register SurfaceHolder.Callback listener
          getHolder().addCallback(this); 

          // initialize Lines and points representing game items
          blocker = new Line(); // create the blocker as a Line
          target = new Line(); // create the target as a Line
          cannonball = new Point(); // create the cannonball as a point

          // initialize hitStates as a boolean array
          hitStates = new boolean[TARGET_PIECES];

          // initialize SoundPool to play the app's three sound effects
          soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

          // create Map of sounds and pre-load sounds
          soundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); // create new HashMap
          soundMap.put(TARGET_SOUND_ID,
             soundPool.load(context, R.raw.target_hit, 1));
          soundMap.put(CANNON_SOUND_ID,
             soundPool.load(context, R.raw.cannon_fire, 1));
          soundMap.put(BLOCKER_SOUND_ID,
             soundPool.load(context, R.raw.blocker_hit, 1));

          // construct Paints for drawing text, cannonball, cannon,
          // blocker and target; these are configured in method onSizeChanged
          textPaint = new Paint(); // Paint for drawing text
          cannonPaint = new Paint(); // Paint for drawing the cannon
          cannonballPaint = new Paint(); // Paint for drawing a cannonball
          blockerPaint = new Paint(); // Paint for drawing the blocker
          targetPaint = new Paint(); // Paint for drawing the target
          backgroundPaint = new Paint(); // Paint for drawing the target
       } // end CannonView constructor

       // called by surfaceChanged when the size of the SurfaceView changes,
       // such as when it's first added to the View hierarchy
       @Override
       protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
       {
          super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

          screenWidth = w; // store the width
          screenHeight = h; // store the height
          cannonBaseRadius = h / 18; // cannon base radius 1/18 screen height
          cannonLength = w / 8; // cannon length 1/8 screen width

          cannonballRadius = w / 36; // cannonball radius 1/36 screen width
          cannonballSpeed = w * 3 / 2; // cannonball speed multiplier

          lineWidth = w / 24; // target and blocker 1/24 screen width

          // configure instance variables related to the blocker
          blockerDistance = w * 5 / 8; // blocker 5/8 screen width from left
          blockerBeginning = h / 8; // distance from top 1/8 screen height
          blockerEnd = h * 3 / 8; // distance from top 3/8 screen height
          initialBlockerVelocity = h / 2; // initial blocker speed multiplier
          blocker.start = new Point(blockerDistance, blockerBeginning);
          blocker.end = new Point(blockerDistance, blockerEnd);

          // configure instance variables related to the target
          targetDistance = w * 7 / 8; // target 7/8 screen width from left
          targetBeginning = h / 8; // distance from top 1/8 screen height
          targetEnd = h * 7 / 8; // distance from top 7/8 screen height
          pieceLength = (targetEnd - targetBeginning) / TARGET_PIECES;
          initialTargetVelocity = -h / 4; // initial target speed multiplier
          target.start = new Point(targetDistance, targetBeginning);
          target.end = new Point(targetDistance, targetEnd);

          // endpoint of the cannon's barrel initially points horizontally
          barrelEnd = new Point(cannonLength, h / 2);

          // configure Paint objects for drawing game elements
          textPaint.setTextSize(w / 20); // text size 1/20 of screen width
          textPaint.setAntiAlias(true); // smoothes the text
          cannonPaint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth * 1.5f); // set line thickness
          blockerPaint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth); // set line thickness      
          targetPaint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth); // set line thickness       
          backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE); // set background color

          newGame(); // set up and start a new game
       } // end method onSizeChanged

       // reset all the screen elements and start a new game
       public void newGame()
       {
          // set every element of hitStates to false--restores target pieces
          for (int i = 0; i < TARGET_PIECES; ++i)
             hitStates[i] = false;

          targetPiecesHit = 0; // no target pieces have been hit
          blockerVelocity = initialBlockerVelocity; // set initial velocity
          targetVelocity = initialTargetVelocity; // set initial velocity
          timeLeft = 10; // start the countdown at 10 seconds
          cannonballOnScreen = false; // the cannonball is not on the screen
          shotsFired = 0; // set the initial number of shots fired
          totalElapsedTime = 0.0; // set the time elapsed to zero
          blocker.start.set(blockerDistance, blockerBeginning);
          blocker.end.set(blockerDistance, blockerEnd);
          target.start.set(targetDistance, targetBeginning);
          target.end.set(targetDistance, targetEnd);

          if (gameOver)
          {
             gameOver = false; // the game is not over
             cannonThread = new CannonThread(getHolder());
             cannonThread.start();
          } // end if
       } // end method newGame

       // called repeatedly by the CannonThread to update game elements
       private void updatePositions(double elapsedTimeMS)
       {
          double interval = elapsedTimeMS / 1000.0; // convert to seconds

          if (cannonballOnScreen) // if there is currently a shot fired
          {
             // update cannonball position
             cannonball.x += interval * cannonballVelocityX;
             cannonball.y += interval * cannonballVelocityY;

             // check for collision with blocker
             if (cannonball.x + cannonballRadius > blockerDistance && 
                cannonball.x - cannonballRadius < blockerDistance &&
                cannonball.y + cannonballRadius > blocker.start.y &&
                cannonball.y - cannonballRadius < blocker.end.y)
             {
                cannonballVelocityX *= -1; // reverse cannonball's direction
                timeLeft -= MISS_PENALTY; // penalize the user

                // play blocker sound
                soundPool.play(soundMap.get(BLOCKER_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
             } // end if

             // check for collisions with left and right walls
             else if (cannonball.x + cannonballRadius > screenWidth || 
                cannonball.x - cannonballRadius < 0)
                cannonballOnScreen = false; // remove cannonball from screen

             // check for collisions with top and bottom walls
             else if (cannonball.y + cannonballRadius > screenHeight || 
                cannonball.y - cannonballRadius < 0)
                cannonballOnScreen = false; // make the cannonball disappear

             // check for cannonball collision with target
             else if (cannonball.x + cannonballRadius > targetDistance && 
                cannonball.x - cannonballRadius < targetDistance && 
                cannonball.y + cannonballRadius > target.start.y &&
                cannonball.y - cannonballRadius < target.end.y)
             {
                // determine target section number (0 is the top)
                int section = 
                   (int) ((cannonball.y - target.start.y) / pieceLength);

                // check if the piece hasn't been hit yet
                if ((section >= 0 && section < TARGET_PIECES) && 
                   !hitStates[section])
                {
                   hitStates[section] = true; // section was hit
                   cannonballOnScreen = false; // remove cannonball
                   timeLeft += HIT_REWARD; // add reward to remaining time

                   // play target hit sound
                   soundPool.play(soundMap.get(TARGET_SOUND_ID), 1,
                      1, 1, 0, 1f);

                   // if all pieces have been hit
                   if (++targetPiecesHit == TARGET_PIECES)
                   {
                      cannonThread.setRunning(false);
                      showGameOverDialog(R.string.win); // show winning dialog
                      gameOver = true; // the game is over
                   } // end if
                } // end if
             } // end else if
          } // end if

          // update the blocker's position
          double blockerUpdate = interval * blockerVelocity;
          blocker.start.y += blockerUpdate;
          blocker.end.y += blockerUpdate;

          // update the target's position
          double targetUpdate = interval * targetVelocity;
          target.start.y += targetUpdate;
          target.end.y += targetUpdate;

          // if the blocker hit the top or bottom, reverse direction
          if (blocker.start.y < 0 || blocker.end.y > screenHeight)
             blockerVelocity *= -1;

          // if the target hit the top or bottom, reverse direction
          if (target.start.y < 0 || target.end.y > screenHeight)
             targetVelocity *= -1;

          timeLeft -= interval; // subtract from time left

          // if the timer reached zero
          if (timeLeft <= 0.0)
          {
             timeLeft = 0.0;
             gameOver = true; // the game is over
             cannonThread.setRunning(false);
             showGameOverDialog(R.string.lose); // show the losing dialog
          } // end if
       } // end method updatePositions

       // fires a cannonball
       public void fireCannonball(MotionEvent event)
       {
          if (cannonballOnScreen) // if a cannonball is already on the screen
             return; // do nothing

          double angle = alignCannon(event); // get the cannon barrel's angle

          // move the cannonball to be inside the cannon
          cannonball.x = cannonballRadius; // align x-coordinate with cannon
          cannonball.y = screenHeight / 2; // centers ball vertically

          // get the x component of the total velocity
          cannonballVelocityX = (int) (cannonballSpeed * Math.sin(angle));

          // get the y component of the total velocity
          cannonballVelocityY = (int) (-cannonballSpeed * Math.cos(angle));
          cannonballOnScreen = true; // the cannonball is on the screen
          ++shotsFired; // increment shotsFired

          // play cannon fired sound
          soundPool.play(soundMap.get(CANNON_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
       } // end method fireCannonball

       // aligns the cannon in response to a user touch
       public double alignCannon(MotionEvent event)
       {
          // get the location of the touch in this view
          Point touchPoint = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

          // compute the touch's distance from center of the screen
          // on the y-axis
          double centerMinusY = (screenHeight / 2 - touchPoint.y);

          double angle = 0; // initialize angle to 0

          // calculate the angle the barrel makes with the horizontal
          if (centerMinusY != 0) // prevent division by 0
             angle = Math.atan((double) touchPoint.x / centerMinusY);

          // if the touch is on the lower half of the screen
          if (touchPoint.y > screenHeight / 2)
             angle += Math.PI; // adjust the angle

          // calculate the endpoint of the cannon barrel
          barrelEnd.x = (int) (cannonLength * Math.sin(angle));
          barrelEnd.y = 
             (int) (-cannonLength * Math.cos(angle) + screenHeight / 2);

          return angle; // return the computed angle
       } // end method alignCannon

       // draws the game to the given Canvas
       public void drawGameElements(Canvas canvas)
       {
          // clear the background
          canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 
             backgroundPaint);

          // display time remaining
          canvas.drawText(getResources().getString(
             R.string.time_remaining_format, timeLeft), 30, 50, textPaint);

          // if a cannonball is currently on the screen, draw it
          if (cannonballOnScreen)
             canvas.drawCircle(cannonball.x, cannonball.y, cannonballRadius,
                cannonballPaint);

          // draw the cannon barrel
          canvas.drawLine(0, screenHeight / 2, barrelEnd.x, barrelEnd.y,
             cannonPaint);

          // draw the cannon base
          canvas.drawCircle(0, (int) screenHeight / 2,
             (int) cannonBaseRadius, cannonPaint);

          // draw the blocker
          canvas.drawLine(blocker.start.x, blocker.start.y, blocker.end.x,
             blocker.end.y, blockerPaint);

          Point currentPoint = new Point(); // start of current target section

          // initialize curPoint to the starting point of the target
          currentPoint.x = target.start.x;
          currentPoint.y = target.start.y;

          // draw the target
          for (int i = 1; i <= TARGET_PIECES; ++i)
          {
             // if this target piece is not hit, draw it
             if (!hitStates[i - 1])
             {
                // alternate coloring the pieces yellow and blue
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                   targetPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                else
                   targetPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                canvas.drawLine(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, target.end.x,
                   (int) (currentPoint.y + pieceLength), targetPaint);
             } // end if

             // move curPoint to the start of the next piece
             currentPoint.y += pieceLength;
          } // end for
       } // end method drawGameElements

       // display an AlertDialog when the game ends
       private void showGameOverDialog(int messageId)
       {
          // create a dialog displaying the given String
          final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = 
             new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
          dialogBuilder.setTitle(getResources().getString(messageId));
          dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

          // display number of shots fired and total time elapsed
          dialogBuilder.setMessage(getResources().getString(
             R.string.results_format, shotsFired, totalElapsedTime));
          dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game,
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                // called when "Reset Game" Button is pressed
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                   dialogIsDisplayed = false;
                   newGame(); // set up and start a new game
                } // end method onClick
             } // end anonymous inner class
          ); // end call to setPositiveButton

          activity.runOnUiThread(
             new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                   dialogIsDisplayed = true;
                   dialogBuilder.show(); // display the dialog
                } // end method run
             } // end Runnable
          ); // end call to runOnUiThread
       } // end method showGameOverDialog

       // stops the game
       public void stopGame()
       {
          if (cannonThread != null)
             cannonThread.setRunning(false);
       } // end method stopGame

       // releases resources; called by CannonGame's onDestroy method 
       public void releaseResources()
       {
          soundPool.release(); // release all resources used by the SoundPool
          soundPool = null; 
       } // end method releaseResources

       // called when surface changes size
       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
          int width, int height)
       {
       } // end method surfaceChanged

       // called when surface is first created
       public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
       {
          if (!dialogIsDisplayed)
          {
             cannonThread = new CannonThread(holder);
             cannonThread.setRunning(true);
             cannonThread.start(); // start the game loop thread
          } // end if
       } // end method surfaceCreated

       // called when the surface is destroyed
       public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
       {
          // ensure that thread terminates properly
          boolean retry = true;
          cannonThread.setRunning(false);

          while (retry)
          {
             try
             {
                cannonThread.join();
                retry = false;
             } // end try
             catch (InterruptedException e)
             {
             } // end catch
          } // end while
       } // end method surfaceDestroyed

       // Thread subclass to control the game loop
       private class CannonThread extends Thread
       {
          private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder; // for manipulating canvas
          private boolean threadIsRunning = true; // running by default

          // initializes the surface holder
          public CannonThread(SurfaceHolder holder)
          {
             surfaceHolder = holder;
             setName("CannonThread");
          } // end constructor

          // changes running state
          public void setRunning(boolean running)
          {
             threadIsRunning = running;
          } // end method setRunning

          // controls the game loop
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
             Canvas canvas = null; // used for drawing
             long previousFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

             while (threadIsRunning)
             {
                try
                {
                   canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);               

                   // lock the surfaceHolder for drawing
                   synchronized(surfaceHolder)
                   {
                      long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                      double elapsedTimeMS = currentTime - previousFrameTime;
                      totalElapsedTime += elapsedTimeMS / 1000.00; 
                      updatePositions(elapsedTimeMS); // update game state
                      drawGameElements(canvas); // draw 
                      previousFrameTime = currentTime; // update previous time
                   } // end synchronized block
                } // end try
                finally
                {
                   if (canvas != null) 
                      surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                } // end finally
             } // end while
          } // end method run
       } // end nested class CannonThread
    } // end class CannonView
```

Line java

```
    // Line.java
    // Class Line represents a line with two endpoints.
    package com.deitel.cannongame;

    import android.graphics.Point;

    public class Line
    {
       public Point start; // starting Point
       public Point end; // ending Point

       // default constructor initializes Points to (0, 0)
       public Line()
       {
          start = new Point(0, 0); // start Point
          end = new Point(0, 0); // end Point
       } // end method Line
    } // end class Line
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit this android game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444065/how-to-edit-this-android-game)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to save score, you have to keep tract of it. what i do in my game is that i save it in SharedPreferences, more on it here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

and the way i do score tracking is to create a class called `GameData` (deriving from Object, no Activity), and implement a static setter and getter for the score, something like this:

```
public class GameData{
    private static final String GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME = "GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME";
    private static final String GAME_DATA_WINS = "GAME_DATA_WINS";
    private static final String GAME_DATA_LOSSES = "GAME_DATA_LOSSES";
    public static void updateGameWinResults(Context ctx, Boolean gameWon){
        if(gameWon){
            ctx.getSharedPreferences(GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(GAME_DATA_WINS, getGameWins(ctx) + 1).commit();
        } else {
            ctx.getSharedPreferences(GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(GAME_DATA_WINS, getGameLosses(ctx) + 1).commit();
        }
    }
    public static int getGameWins(Context ctx)
        SharedPreferences sp = c.getSharedPreferences(GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return sp.getInt(GAME_DATA_WINS, 0);
    }
    public static int getGameLosses(Context ctx){
        SharedPreferences sp = c.getSharedPreferences(GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return sp.getInt(GAME_DATA_LOSSES, 0);
    }
}
```

and of course, in your code, from ANYWHERE in the activity (although i recommend you stick the saving part somewhere when the game ends and you're trying to save data), you just simply call:

```
GameData.updateGameWinResults(this,false); // if they lost... give it a true if they won
```

and to get wins, do :

```
int wins = GameData.getGameWins(this);
```

or for losses do :

```
int losses = GameData.getGameLosses(this);
```

or even to get total games played (assuming only win and losses):

```
int gamesPlayed = GameData.getGameWins(this) + GameData.getGameLosses(this);
```

as for the saving options, that's also easily doable using the same mechanism. make sense?

but this answer is starting to get really long though. if you are confused about the other parts (after you've tried out ppl's solutions, i'd recommend asking it as a separate question, just about the other options. that way, you give an opportunity to give Stack Overflow users more points anyways, by upvoting and accepting)